# Fast method for evaluating at a single point the solution to a boundary value problem for a linear second-order elliptic PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, monte-carlo, elliptic-equations

I have a PDE of the form $\Delta q(z) + \vec F(z)\cdot\nabla q(z) + G(z)=0$, for $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with boundary condition $\nabla q(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$.  If I only need to compute $\nabla q$ at a single point $z_0$, and only to a low precision, what's the fastest way to do that?

The only method I've come across which may address this is the [method of random walks on balls](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3327/710883d560f31ec360f6ce76bc8217196e7d.pdf), which does [not seem to have gotten much traction in the literature](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13045490404758480973&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en).  Are there any others?